# If someone couldn't finish his Al-Fatiha recitation behind an imam, is it valid if he makes up that rakah at the end?

Tags: salat

Today when I was praying behind the Imam in Salatul Isha, he was reciting very quickly (he usually recites slower) so at the third rakah, I didn't have time to finish Surah Al-Fatiha, and in the fourth rakah, I did finish Al-Fatiha but I missed ruku'. So after the imam made the Salam, I didn't make Salam and I prayed one rakah because I didn't complete Al-Fatiha in the third rakah. Is this valid?

Comment: Why? The prayer of the imam is a prayer for you. But you should speak to the imam and tell him.

Comment: Because of that Hadith that says there's no salah for the one who doesn't recite Al-Fatiha

Comment: That refers to at least one recitation in the prayer. And the hadith is interpreted differently by scholars. And third and girth raka'a are the part where scholars agree that the prayer of the imam is a prayer for you.